# GeoDataFrame - Unable to select range of linestrings

Tags: geodataframe

```
df = sample['geometry']
line_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[df[2],  df[3], df[4], df[5], df[6], df[7], df[8], df[9]])
```

Above is the manual process of selecting Line Strings

In order to select from 2:180 I tried some code without luck

```
line_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[df[df.rows[2:4]])
```

it comes up with an error of'GeoSeries' object has no attribute 'rows'

I am bit confused how to solve it I would appriciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "sample" is a GeoDataFrame, then df in your example is a GeoSeries of geometries. As GeoSeries don't have rows, df.rows give you the error you report.

Its unclear to me exactly what you are trying to achieve, but I assume you have a dataframe  called sample, and you want to select rows 2 to 180. If so:

```
line_gdf = sample.iloc[2:180]
```

If you are trying to achieve something else, please clarify your inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for !